# How to de-serialize List of List to List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Please show me, how to deserialize this one in XmlSerializer

```
<Root>
   <Ship KindID=0>
      <Ship0 Name='A' />
      <Ship1 Name='B' />
      <Ship2 Name='C' />
   </Ship>
   <Ship KindID=1>
      <Ship3 Name='AA' />
      <Ship4 Name='BB' />
      <Ship4 Name='cC' />
   </Ship>
</Root>
```

To

```
public class Ships {
   public List<Ship> Ships {get; set;}
}
public class Ship {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int KindID {get;set;}
}
```

I want the way to deserialize without navigating all xml path manual. Just do XmlSerializer.Deserialize(mem, obj)

Thanks

Comment: serializable **by which serializer**?

Comment: I don't known how to do that in C#. Only tried in ActionScript 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialize something like that.

```
var reader = new StreamReader("Path of the xml");
var shipCollection = (List<Ship>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Once you have collection you can use Linq

```
var shipNameCollection =  shipCollection.Where( t=> t.Name != null).ToList();
```

You will have list of names of all the ships

Comment: can you please explain the reason? I am using such deserializer all the times

Comment: @Peter PAD, it would be better to put this in the question. Also consider revising/deleting your comments to be more polite.

Comment: what about var output = (List<Ship>) new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ship)).Deserialize(/*Your stream*/);

Comment: Answer is in the code above. If you want go through the example here is the link of an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx